# Java String not equal String?

Tags: java, string, cryptography, aes

I want to `decrypt` a `String`. Here my `Decryption` and `Encryption` methods.

```
public String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    byte[] messageInBytes = message.getBytes();
    encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptionCipher.doFinal(messageInBytes);
    return encode(encryptedBytes);
}
```

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) throws Exception {
    byte[] messageInBytes = decode(encryptedMessage);
    Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(T_LEN , encryptionCipher.getIV());
    decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = decryptionCipher.doFinal(messageInBytes);
    return new String(decryptedBytes);
}
```

Here the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AES aes = new AES();
        aes.convertStringKeyToSecretKey();
        String encryptedMessage = aes.encrypt("Peter");
        String decryptedMessage = aes.decrypt(encryptedMessage);

        System.err.println("Encrypted Message : " + encryptedMessage);
        System.err.println("Decrypted Message : " + decryptedMessage);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

When I change `encryptedMessage` to a own `String` like:

```
String decryptedMessage = aes.decrypt("xDFzl9HsenqKspdEbL/m9I5X6dqn");
```

It does nothing

I hope you can help me.

Best Regards

Christian

Comment: Why ignore thrown exceptions? They will probably tell you something useful about what’s wrong.

Comment: Your `encryption()` and `decryption()` method have a hidden connection: the `decryption()` method uses `encryptionCipher.getIV()` which is initialized by the `encryption()` method. If you call `aes.decrypt()` only you are probably using the wrong IV.

Comment: The solution is to use the IV/nonce generated during encryption also during decryption. This is typically done by concatenating IV/nonce and ciphertext during encryption (iv|ciphertext) and passing them to the decrypting side, which can separate the two based on the known IV/nonce length (12 bytes for GCM). Btw, the same problem exists for the GCM tag, but Java does the concatenation/separation automatically (ciphertext|tag), so you don't even notice that.

Comment: Oh man why is encryption in Java so much more difficult xD
Well I wan't to decrypt an encrypted String that is saved in a file.
So I do not run always the encryption method directly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String encryptAES(String toEncrypt, final String key1, final String key2) throws Exception {
            try {
                byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

                SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
                KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key1.toCharArray(), key2.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
                SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
        }

        public static String decryptAES(String toDecrypt, final String key1, final String key2) throws Exception {
            try {
                byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

                SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
                KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key1.toCharArray(), key2.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
                SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

                return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(toDecrypt)));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
        }
```

Here you can still expand its secureness by creating your own IV Spec key, which should contain only 16 character.

Actually, this is how AES encryption worked for me, You can also check this repo in [GitHub](https://github.com/Vicky2004-maker/Cypher-Library/blob/main/src/com/clevergo/cypherlib/Cypher.java) for additional encryption methods.

Comment: For this solution to be secure, a _random_ key must be used for _each_ encryption because of the static IV. With a fixed passphrase (`key1`) this is only achieved by generating a fresh, random salt (`key2`) for each encryption. Therefore it would make sense to generate the salt directly in `encryptAES()` and to concatenate it with the ciphertext so that it is available during decryption. Also note that this is not authenticated encryption.